# How to add sample text to an autopilot taks via twilio CLI?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I already have several autopilot tasks with only one sample text that I've been using to test functionality. Now I'm ready to start adding more samples to each tasks to better train the model. How can I add them using Twilio CLI?

I found this command `twilio api:autopilot:v1:assistants:tasks:list --assistant-sid UAXXX` and I got a list with all my tasks, but how can I add more sample text?

I think the command `api:autopilot:v1:assistants:tasks:update` could be useful but is not [documented](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/api/task#update-a-task-resource).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heyoooo Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

Thanks for raising that the docs could be improved, i'll forward this feedback. To update samples you can use the following command

```
twilio api:autopilot:v1:assistants:tasks:samples:create --task-sid=UD46...  --assistant-sid=UA5f... --language=en-US --tagged-text="hello ceochronos"
```

*I'm running `v1.8.1` of the Twilio CLI.*

---

How did I find this out? :) When working with the Twilio CLI I recommend to enable auto-completion. You can have a look at [this article](https://www.twilio.com/blog/five-twilio-cli-features-you-should-know-about) for auto-completion and other cool CLI features. :)

Using auto-completion you can navigate around and discover functionality by just tabbing in the terminal.

[image: Terminal showing Twilio CLI auto completion]

After you found the command you're looking for `--help` is your best friend. :)

[image]

I hope this helps. :)

Edited: you can have also a look at [the autopilot cli](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/twilio-autopilot-cli) which will integrate in the twilio cli soon.

Comment: That's just amazing @stefan for some reason I forgot about `--help`

_ahem_, any insight in this other issue :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58651590/how-to-send-several-messages-using-twilio-autopilot#comment103628102_58652443

Comment: Happy to help. :)